# Stateless Function in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, static, stateless

If we consider a function foo depending on a and b. Would I then write a stateless function as follows:

```
MyClass

final b;

<returnType> foo(a) {...}
```

I am asking because foo would depend on the state of the MyClass-object. However, that state is final, and so foo will always return the same result for a given a.

Following the functional paradigm in a dogmatic way, i.e. letting functions only depend on their inputs/arguments, would mean that:

```
MyClass

<returnType> foo(a, b) {...}
```

Then, however, foo can be made static. So, would a dogmatic application of the functional style always lead to static methods?

Thank you!

Comment: If `b` is final, it can be used within `foo` without adding it as an argument. It *isn't* going to change. Whether you have `x -> x * PI` or `x -> x * 3.14` the difference hardly matters if `PI = 3.14` and it can never be different.

Comment: You can think of `this` (which you will either explicitly write or imply when you refer to the `b` field) in instance methods as the first parameter `foo`. This is sort of how it works in bytecode. It depends on what you think really, and what you think is "dogmatic". Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: "*So, would a dogmatic application of the functional style always lead to static methods?*" yes but that would be because OOP doesn't model functional approach very well. `static` has a slightly odd place in OO design because it's an admittance that not only objects and their state matters. And function programming fully embraces that, so *technically* if you were to represent FP via OO, then pretty much all methods should be static. But that's because Java doesn't (really) have free functions.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you. And that would also be ok if b is not a constant value like PI, right? It only matters that it is immutable. That means, I can instantiate MyClass with some b and then it would be ok?

Comment: Slight caveat: just because a field is `final` doesn't mean that it represents a constant value. A very clear example would be a `final List<String> x`: while you can't reassign a *different* `List` object to `x`, the *content* of the `List` can in fact change! For a truly constant value you'll need *both* a `final` field and an immutable type (such as `String`).

Comment: @chipsmonster91 yes, I used Pi as an example. It could be anything else that will remain the same for the execution of the application. E.g., `final startTime` can record the time the application was started and would not change. Yes, next execution it would but we're interested in things that don't change *during* the execution. A more practical example might be a DB name that comes from config at startup. If you change the database, you need to restart but in the mean time it's always the same.

Comment: It's a `final` field, not a `static final` one, so its value may even be different for each instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact terminology, you could say that a *dogmatic* application of functional style always leads to static methods. However, in my view, dogmatically following some style is always a bad idea.

I would say, that in an object oriented programming language like Java, every method has an implicit additional parameter containing the `this` reference, that is, the reference to the object of which the method is called. If you adopt this view, then it is still "functional style" if you call non-static methods.

Note that you wouldn't even be allowed to call simple getters, otherwise.

Comment: "All absolutes are always bad" ;-)